# LINQ Expression for Contains

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I want to add dynamic expression in linq but facing issues on contains method it is working perfectly for Equal method

Problem is i'm getting `FilterField` dynamically how to replace in query

So far i had tried

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();  
**string filterField ="DEPARTMENT"; ==> Dynamic Field**

var eParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EmployeeDetail), "e");

var comparison = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(eParam, filterField), Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(Ids), Expression.Property(eParam, filterField).Type));

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<EmployeeDetail, bool>>(comparison, eParam);

var countMonthly1 = ctx.tblMonthlyInput.Join(ctx.tblEmployee, a => a.CompanyId, b => b.CompanyId, (a, b) => b).Where(lambda).Count();
```

I want to make above query works for Contains method using linq expression

sample query  :

```
var countMonthly = (from a in ctx.tblMonthlyInput
                    join b in ctx.tblEmployee on a.CompanyId equals b.CompanyId
                    where categoryId.Contains(a.CategoryId)  //want to make this dynamic
                    select a).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: Could you post code that compiles?

Comment: You'll need to get the method of `List.Contains` and invoke it via `Expression.Call()`.

Comment: @Thomas sample query which i have mentioned compiles properly but problem is i want to make (`a.CategoryId`) dynamic

Comment: @rob i had tried the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460913/linq-expressionfunct-bool-equavalent-of-contains but dont know it is not working as expected

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
void Main()
{
    var filterField = "Id";
    List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
    var eParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EmployeeDetail), "e");
    var method = Ids.GetType().GetMethod("Contains");
    var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Ids), method, Expression.Property(eParam, filterField));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<EmployeeDetail, bool>>(call, eParam);
}

public class EmployeeDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

First, you look for the `Contains` method on the type of `Ids`. Then we simply invoke it with `Ids` as the instance, and the property as the argument